# right way to write script in html file

Tags: javascript, html, head

I have written a script in HTML, but i don't know the best way to place script in HTML.

**1.In Head**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script></script>
    <head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**2. After Body**

```
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body></body>
    <script></script>
</html>
```

**3. After Html**

```
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body></body>
</html>
<script></script>
```

Comment: Write in a separate file and add its src in the script tag

Comment: Your second and third options would be invalid HTML. This may be helpful: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax

Answer (score 2):

According to Yahoo performance team the `<script>` should be placed at the bottom of the page. But the problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads which might slow the page.

Another suggestion is to use `async` and `defer`. The `async` and `defer` HTML attributes let you control when and how JavaScript files are downloaded and executed. Using these attributes, you can reduce the amount of time users spend waiting on JavaScript without having to change your scripts.

[**Reference**](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Answer (score 0):

The Right way for writing Script is below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script></script>
    <head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

2 and 3 are technically incorrect but probably work in browsers.

For performance in website write script like below.

```
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <script></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have any reference for this

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body></body>
    <script></script>
</html>
```